# Is the pig optimizer filtering nulls before joining?

Tags: join, optimization, apache-pig

I'm confused by pig's performance documentation about joining with null value across inputs. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/perf.html#nulls

As the doc correctly states: "the nulls from A and B won't be collected together", so it makes perfect sense for the optimizer to filter them before joining:

```
A1 = filter A by t is not null;
B1 = filter B by x is not null;
C = join A1 by t, B1 by x;
```

Is the pig optimizer automatically doing this? Or is it a recommendation for the user to remember and do it every time? If its not automatic, is it a reasonable contribution to make?

Reason I'm asking is that we had numerous performance issues and the root cause turned out to be exactly this :(

Comment: As you said, it should be doing it. It is a performance optimization that is enabled by default, or so it states in the official documentation. If you are certain that it is not doing it and you haven't touched the optimization rules, perhaps you have found a bug and would be nice posting it in [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG).

Comment: ok, added a request to the jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4662

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer for the others who checking this question...

Based on the documentation:

In the join result you won't have any null joined by the other null, it's dropping it, but just at the end.

> "So the null keys will be dropped. But they will not be dropped until
>   the last possible moment."

So to optimize it you can filter them out before join (as the doc says).
So I think that's not a bug, but you're right this could be done by the optimizer.

Comment: it *should* :) an unoptimized join of this type wasted some precious hours for me personally